# Exclude <head> with PHP - Is this bad in terms of SEO?

Tags: php, seo, head

Sorry for my stupid question, but I just started to deal with SEO.
Here is the thing:
I have a quite long list of meta tags and links in the html-head. In order to simplify and centralize the maintenance I'd like to exclude the entire HEAD with PHP to a separate file.

Is that a problem in terms of SEO?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

**No** , its not bad term you can do this since php is server side languages  ..  php  The code is interpreted by a Web server with a PHP processor module which generates the resulting Web page **PHP files are returned to the browser as plain HTML**

> [**PHP is HTML embedded scripting language:**](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/php/index.shtml) This means that PHP statements and commands are actually embedded in your HTML documents. When the Web server sees the PHP statements in the Web page, the server executes the statements and sends the resulting output along with the rest of the HTML. PHP commands are parsed by the server

So either you include header by yourself or by php both are same effect and not bad practice for SEO  .

this is how php works

[image]

<sub><sub>[image source](http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson1.php)</sub></sub>

what the search engine see will he html page not php so dont worry

Comment: +1 for a pretty picture. Also @SvenKruse If this is your chosen answer then 'tick' it to mark it as so :)

Comment: I would like to but it says "Vote-up requires 15 reputations". I just signed-up.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the final HTML code stays the same, I don't see how SEO will be affected at all.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast answer. Does it mean that Google will only see the included HTML code instead of the PHP code?